# How to return value without terminating the function?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Here it returns 0.2 because it stops the function without waiting for the iteration of the timer.

```lua
function Ani.Speed(maxSpeed, phase)
    if(phase == accelerate) then   
        function speedUp()
            if(maxSpeed ~= 0) then
                maxSpeed = 0
            end
            returnedSpeed = maxSpeed + 0.2
            return(returnedSpeed)
        end
        timer.performWithDelay(1000, speedUp, 10)
    end

end
```

How to return the maxSpeed at each iteration?

*Expected result:*

```lua
print(maxSpeed) -- 0/0.2/0.4/0.6/(...)/2, where "/" is interval in second
```

Comment: Use coroutines, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a local array variable before timer.performWithDelay and add all maxSpeed to the array inside speedUp function. After timer.performWithDelay, return the array.

As requested, please find below the suggested code:

```
if(phase == accelerate) then
    returnedSpeed = []
    i = 0 #(array index)
    function speedUp()
        if(maxSpeed ~= 0) then
            maxSpeed = 0
        end
        returnedSpeed[i] = maxSpeed + 0.2
        i = i + 1
    end
    timer.performWithDelay(1000, speedUp, 10)
    return(returnedSpeed) 
end
```

Comment: At first, `2:unexpected symbol near '['`

Comment: You've shared the error. The code I've given is an algorithm / concept. You've to tweak to your programming language.

Comment: Well, okay then. However, I found a way to bypass all the function with a timer in my code, but thanks anyway. You will be able to help other people with it.